# Extract the value of namespace declaration using xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I've got an XML document with the declaration

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.04" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.04 file://BE-FILE01/tverschu$/SR%20(Standards%20Release)/SR2013/ISO/Payments%20Initiation/SR2013_MX_Schemas_PaymentsInitiation/pain.008.001.04.xsd">
```

Effectively I want to use XPath(1.0) within an XSLT trasnfromation to get at the contents of either the `xmlns` namespace attribute, or the `xsi:schemaLocation` attrubite, so I can strip out / recreate the name of an xsd file.

using:

```
/*/namespace::*
```

gives me

> http>//wwww.w3.org/XML/1998/Namespace

but whatever I try I don't seem able to get the actual contents of these attributes, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to query `@schemaLocation` using `/*/@xsi:schemaLocation`.

`xmlns` "attributes" are namespaces declarations, not attributes. You cannot query them as such. `/*/namespace::*` works totally fine for me. Is `/*` querying the `<Document/>` tag? The `xml` namespace can always set, did you check *all* returned values?